# Rename column name to sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a task to update data to a master table on daily basis, i.e. I'm adding new column called 'TODAY' NUMBER to my master table and successfully writing data but unable to rename column TODAY with SYSDATE

```
ALTER TABLE DATA_HIST 
RENAME COLUMN TODAY TO SYSDATE;
```

I'm getting invalid identifier error for above script

also tried below with TO_CHAR but unsuccessful

```
ALTER TABLE DATA_HIST 
RENAME COLUMN TODAY TO TO_CHAR(SYSDATE);
```

Thanks in advance
Nash

Comment: I assume SYSDATE is a reserved word. Try "SYSDATE", or chose a better column name.

Answer (score 4):

Escape the column name with double quotes:

```
ALTER TABLE DATA_HIST 
RENAME COLUMN TODAY TO "SYSDATE";
```

But in general you should avoid naming your tables and columns after keywords or system function names.

Comment: upvoted for avoiding that stuff. Don't create potential for errors in future querys when you don't have to.

Comment: @Magisch Sometimes we are stuck with things like this, but yes always best to avoid a potential problem.

Comment: Just another reason to avoid, each time you need to access that column, you always have to use the double quotes

Comment: Thanks for response Tim. But I'm trying to rename column field with actual date i.e. 20/10/2017 which is SYSDATE in this case. If I use "SYSDATE" then column name will get renamed to SYSDATE instead of value 20/10/2017

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  This would mean that the column name would keep changing.  In any case I think you would need dynamic SQL to do this.

Comment: Thanks Tim, any suggestions of renaming column using dynamic SQL! 
My current task is to store performance score on daily basis
Thanks
Nash